# How do I write a predicate that returns a specific list?

Tags: prolog

I am attempting to write a predicate that will identify the following changeover destinations.

The places at which it is possible to change flight are Amsterdam, Bangkok, London, New York, San Francisco and Sydney. So I should have the following result when the query changeover is made:

```
?- changeover(X).
X = amsterdam ;
X = bangkok ;
X = london ;
X = new_york ;
X = san_francisco ;
X = sydney.
```

I currently have this:

```
changeover(X):- destinations(X).
```

This prints all the destinations as expected, but how do I get to print only the required destinations? Am I correct in thinking I need recursion?

I have a prolog database, which contains the following:

```
destinations([abidjan, abu_dhabi, amsterdam, aruba, athens, baltimore,
bangkok, bermuda, brisbane, buenos_aires, colombo, dakar, dubai,
hamburg, harare, hong_kong, honolulu, johannesburg, lagos, lima,
lisbon, london, mahe, nairobi, new_york, panama, perth, quito,
rio, san_francisco, santiago, singapore, sydney, tokyo]).
```

Comment: What is "required" ? Generally it would be `changeover(X):- destinations(X), required(X).`

Comment: Yes, you need to define what you mean by *required*. Also, representing all destinations in a single fact with a list is not good Prolog programming practice in general. It's better to have individual facts, `destination(abidjan).`, `destination(abu_dhabi).`, etc. You could also either have separate facts for *changeover*, such as, `changeover(sydney).`, `changeover(new_york).`, etc. Or, you can have a compound fact for each city which has that as an argument: `destination(abidjan, terminal).`, `destination(amsterdam, changeover).`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can define `changeover/1` directly by specifying all instances for which the relation holds:

```
changeover(amsterdam).
changeover(bangkok).
changeover(london).
changeover(new_york).
changeover(san_francisco).
changeover(sydney).
```

Answer (score 0):

if destinations is a list, then you need to do something like

```
changeover(X) :- destinations(D), member(X, D), required(X).
```

`required` is a predicate that determines required destinations - it's not exactly clear what you want to do

Comment: by required i mean i only want changeover(x) to return X = amsterdam ;
X = bangkok ;
X = london ;
X = new_york ;
X = san_francisco ;
X = sydney.

Comment: Well, then you could just do `changeover(X) :- member(X, [amsterdam, bangkok, london, new_york, san_francisco, sydney])` (that is, if there isn't any more sophisticated way of telling what you want to return)